# Как и где можно уместить 32 битовых флага?

Tags: c++

Насколько я понимаю, unsigned char может вместить в себя 8 флагов, а что можно придумать, чтобы уместить 32 флага?

Comment: `unsigned int` в современном компиляторе. А еще лучше `bitset<>`.

Comment: `#include <cstdint> ... std::uint32_t flags = 0b1010110011U;`.

Comment: `uint32_t` из `stdint.h`

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Объявляю например unsigned int. Как все биты выставить в 0? и Как потом взвести например 15й бит?

Comment: `uint32_t v; v = 0; v |= (1 << 15);`

Comment: @avp а как теперь пройтись по всем битам и понять какие из них взведены?)

Comment: В первую очередь поискать информацию по битовым операциям в C++. Вы же не собираетесь спрашивать про буквально каждое интересующее вас действие? :) Вывод всех битов от старшего к младшему: `for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) cout << ( (flags >> i) & 1U );`

Comment: @wololo действительно, было излишне) всех благодарю)

Comment: @Максим, смотрите множество приемов в [bithacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) (которых никогда не было, нет и не будет в крестовом bitset -))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у вас С++, используйте тип из стандартной библиотеки, который по сути для этого и предназначен — [`bitset<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), который обеспечивает именно хранение набора битовых флагов.

Тридцать два? Без проблем: `bitset<32> bs`...

Установить k-й бит? `bs.set(k)`

Получить k-й бит? `bs[k]`

Работать с конкретными целочисленными типами можно, конечно... Но это подход из С, а не С++.

Answer (score 1):

Как я бы сделал на твоем месте. Cоздал объект std::bitset с размером 32 бита, чтобы хранить 32 флага:

```
std::bitset<32> flags;
```

Далее возьми переменные типа unsigned int или unsigned long, они обычно весят 32 бита:

```
unsigned int flags = 0;
// установить флаг номер 0
flags |= 1 << 0;
// сбросить флаг номер 5
flags &= ~(1 << 5);
```

Если это не поможет, возьми классы или структуры с битовыми полями, чтобы уместить более 32 флага в одной переменной:

```
struct Flags{
  unsigned int flag0 : 1;
  unsigned int flag1 : 1;
  unsigned int flag2 : 1;
  ...
  unsigned int flag31 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Не гарантируется, что unsigned int занимает 32 бита.